# What is the proper way to iterate through an IObservableList<T>?

Tags: c#, loops, reactiveui

I'm working on a WPF application that utilizes ReactiveUI and DynamicData. Most of our lists are of the type IObservableList and at times we need to subscribe to changes on this list, and at times we need to simply iterate through the list. My concern is around if we're following the correct pattern for iterating through these lists.

Currently, when we need to iterate through a list, we follow the following pattern:

```
// Assuming we have an IObservableList<SomeObject> named objList with some data in it
foreach (var obj in objList.Items)
{
    // some operation on obj
}
```

This pattern works fine, but we're concerned that this isn't a "Reactive" way to do this. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: `What is the proper way to iterate through an IObservableList<T>` it depends...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ On anything in particular?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Say I just need to iterate through the list and have no need for it to be reactive to plot something. I just want to know if this is the suitable/accepted way to do this.

Comment: The question is vague and does not admit an answer because you have not said what the "some operation" is; if that operation is logically a *projection*, for instance, then you should be using `Select` rather than a loop, and producing a *new* observable sequence of projected items.  What is the operation in the loop?

Comment: Not trying to be vague, but it doesn't really matter what the operation is. I'm just asking what the correct approach to iterating through an observable list is if we know that we don't care about any reactive elements when looping through it.

If you really need an example, let's use the following (assume the list has 10 integers):

`foreach (var i in tenInts.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int);
}`

Comment: It does matter what the operation is, is my point. If the operation is logically an *action* -- that is, useful for only its side effects and not because it produces a value -- then `foreach` is the right thing to do. But as I said, that's *possibly* not the right thing to do if the operation is, say, a projection.

Comment: All I'm trying to ask is if there is another approach to iterating through an observable collection. The foreach isn't even really the main question, but rather if using `.Items` to iterate through the list is frowned upon or correct.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through a list using a loop. Each of them works.

for is the obvious first candidate.

while works, but is a bit more writing.

foreach works - **if** you do not start changing the list. A quirk of foreach is that it only works with enumerators under the hood, and enumerators become invalid if the collection is changed.

One particulay thing to consider however is the "ElementAdded" Notification on (re)building the list. Usually they classes lack AddRange functions.

Unless you tell us what you **do** with SomeClass Instances during itteration and how the class looks, we can not tell you if it is "reactive" programming. But for me it feels like it is just a Buzzword.

Comment: I guess my question boils down to this: is there some other pattern to iterate through such a list besides essentially converting it to an IEnumerable with the `.Items` paradigm.

Comment: Depends if you need it to be reactive. Eg if you want to iterate on items every time the list changes that's a different matter.

Comment: So what I'm seeing is that under circumstances where we just need the current state of the list, this is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yeah for cases where you aren't reacting to changes to the SourceList just iterate over it.

Comment: I was recently told that foreach is a bit slower, actually. Up to half the speed, actually. the logic makes sense - you got an extra Enumerator with it's itterator and it's checks to go through - but I am not sure if the JiT can not deal with that part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not quite familiarized with `IObservableList<T>`, but I use [Deferred Execution](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution) when working with `IList<T>`.

I would recommend to implement this when working with dynamic data, it will let you get the latest values whenever you need them.

check the link for more details.

Comment: Don't think this helps with the https://GitHub.com/ReactiveUI/dynamicdata